# How to use an array in for loop to calculate minimum?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to use an array, but I am not sure if that is the right way to do this.

I want the first and second integer input to compare with one another, then if there are more they compare with each other.

So here is the piece of the code.

```
for(int ii = 1, j = 0; j <= copySel ; ii++, j++) {     
             int x = 0;
             int[x] check;
                // Prompt as follows
                System.out.print("Enter value " + ii + ": ");
                try {
                    c = Get();
                }
                catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    // Display the following text in the event of an invalid input
                    System.out.println("Invalid input!");
                    ii--; x--;
                } check = c; x++;    

                System.out.print(check + " "+ x);
        }
```

My actual format is not this bad. I need to try to find the minimum value depending on the number of integer the user has input

```
static int Get()
    {
        Scanner intFind = new Scanner(System.in);
        int select;
        select = intFind.nextInt();
        return select;
    }
```

This is Get() ^

cant I use min(x, y) continuously?

Comment: isn't this is homework? Also what is your question?

Comment: if its a homework, add a tag of it. I have also added

Comment: Someone told me not to, because they will remove that soon.

Comment: @FahimParkar The homework tag was deprecated a couple months ago. From Tag Description **This tag is OBSOLETE and is in the process of being removed. But don't remove it without looking at the question to see if it needs cleanup. Please see [this question on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag) for more information.
**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 System.out.print("Enter value " + ii + ": ");
 int min = Get();
 int c = 0;
 for(int ii = 1, j = 0; j < copySel ; ii++, j++) { 

            // Prompt as follows
            System.out.print("Enter value " + ii + ": ");
            try {
                c = Get();
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                // Display the following text in the event of an invalid input
                System.out.println("Invalid input!");
                ii--;
            } min = Math.min(min, c);   

            System.out.print("minimum is:"+ min);
    }
```

Comment: if you want to use ur code you can use the following, u don't have the use clone since Get() doesn't return an array of integer but it returns only 1 int

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
int min=a[0];

for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    if(a[i] < min) 
         min = a[i];
}

System.out.println("The min is "+min);
```

Comment: What do you mean by this, does it go in the original for loop?

Comment: what is n here I think n is a.length

Comment: cant I use min(x, y) continuously?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what your trying to do exactly, but here's some errors you might consider to repair. If check is an array you have to initialize it as such:

```
int[] check;
```

Does get() give you back an array of integer, if so you cannot make check = c, you have to copy or clone the content of c into check as such:

```
check = (int[])c.clone();
```

Comment: I have to get the minimum value

Comment: I need to try to find the minimum value depending on the number of integers the user has input

Comment: ok then the most straight forward way is to use Mandar's way,

Comment: cant I use min(x, y) continuously?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a integer array you could do as below

```
  Integer [] arr = {5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
  Collections.sort(list);
  System.out.println("Minimum "+list.get(0)); ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter the integers: ");
 String s = in.nextLine();
 string[] str = s.plit(" ");
 int[] a = new a[str.length];
 for(int i =0; i< str.length; i++)
 {
     a[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
 }
 //Madar's code
 int min=a[0];

for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    min = Math.min(a[i], min);
}

System.out.println("The min is "+min);
```

Comment: cant I use min(x, y) continuously?

Comment: yes indeed you can instead of the if statement you can write         min = Math.min(a[i], min);