# How to calculate the minimum value using min(x, y) in a for loop? Dependent on user input

Tags: java, for-loop, min

So I have been trying to tackle this problem for a while. Many things I have attempted have failed. Is there a way to add to what I already have?

```
for(int ii = 1, j = 0; j <= copySel ; ii++, j++) {    
             int check;
             int x, y;
                // Prompt as follows
                System.out.print("Enter value " + ii + ": ");
                try {
                    c = Get();
                }
                catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    input
                    System.out.println("Invalid input!");
                    ii--;
                }check = c;   
                 x = check; // I want to try to copy this 
                 y = check - 1; // and copy this
                min(x , y) // trying to acheive this




                System.out.println(check + " " + x + " " + y);

        }
```

Sorry about the formatting. It is my screen.

```
Basically let us say user puts in 25 for first input. I want x = 25.
Then user inputs -11.                                 I want y = -11.
Compare minimum                                       z = -11.
then                                                  x = z = -11;
User input 33.                                        y = 33
annd so on..
```

So i ended up with something like

```
for(int ii = 1, j = 0; j <= copySel ; ii++, j++) {    
             int check;
             int x = 0, y = 0, z;
                // Prompt as follows
                System.out.print("Enter value " + ii + ": ");
                try {
                    c = Get();
                }
                catch (InputMismatchException e) {

                    System.out.println("Invalid input!");
                    ii--;
                }check = c;
               x = check;
               z = x;   
            if (j % 2 == 1)
            {
                y = check;
                Math.min(z, y);
            }


                System.out.println(check + " " + x + " " + y + " " + z);

        }
```

Comment: Do you want to find minimum of just two numbers? And please post one of the many things that you have tried.

Comment: It will be more than two if the user decides on setting up 3 or 4 to compare

Comment: Didn't this question of yours solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356400/how-to-use-an-array-in-for-loop-to-calculate-minimum

Comment: Won't `y` always be `x - 1`? It seems silly to calculate the min value; it will always be `y` at that point in the program. Also, what do you want to do with the min value? Store it somewhere?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Don't just paste some code that is not working. Explain what you want to do and what (exactly i.e. error messages, exceptions,...) is not working.

Comment: No the loops don't work for my code. I want to store the min value somewhere ... Yes

Comment: In your explanation, where did `z` come from? What is `check` in your code supposed to be? Do you just want to find the minimum of all the values the user entered? Perhaps if you gave your variables meaningful names, it would help us understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to get the minimum value from the current input and last minimum value. Definitely it will be the minimum of all the numbers provided.
Then all you need is to save minimum value from the last turn and compare it with input in the next one.

```
for(int ii = 1, j = 0; j <= copySel ; ii++, j++) {  //btw, what is 'j' for? attempt count?
         boolean mode; //true = minimum, false = maximum
         boolean firstNumber = true;
         int check; //user input
         int lastValue; //will be the storage
            // Prompt as follows
            System.out.print("Enter value " + ii + ": ");
            try {
                c = Get();
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                input
                System.out.println("Invalid input!");
                ii--;
            }
             check = c;
             if (firstNumber) { //first input has nothing to compare with
                 lastValue = check;
                 firstNumber = false;
                 continue;
             }
             lastValue = mode ? min(check, lastValue) : max(check, lastValue);
             /* you should also implement max() method if you want to be able to find maximum
             *  if you don't, just write lastValue = min(check, lastValue);
             *  and remove other 'mode' dependancies.
             */


             System.out.println((mode ? "minimum is: " : "maximum is: ") + String.valueOf(lastValue));

    }
```

hope I have understood your problem correct.

Comment: only problem is the print statement needs to be outside

Comment: This was a difficult problem I prefer finishing it and getting it right